# ASP.NET core 3 ActionFilter and Viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a webpage containing some simple text fields and a dropdownlist. The values of this dropdownlist come from a database table and are populated via the Viewbag.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories" class="form-control"></select>
    <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

For validation of my forms I'm trying to use an actionfilter.

```
public class ModelValidationFilter : Attribute, IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
        {
            //Not needed
        }

        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Result = new ViewResult()
                {
                    ViewData = ((Controller)context.Controller).ViewData,
                    TempData = ((Controller)context.Controller).TempData,
                    StatusCode = 400
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

This works really well, except for the dropdownlist, it seems like the viewbag is cleared.
Is there any way to make this construct work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have passed tempdata to new result in actionfilter,you can use TempData to replace ViewBag.Here is a demo(.net core 3.1):

Controller(TempData cannot accept List in .net core3.1,so i serialize it in action and deserialize it in view):

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var Categories=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new List<SelectListItem> { new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "c1" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "c2" }, new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "c3" } });
            TempData["Categories"] = Categories;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ModelValidationFilter]
        public IActionResult Index(Category c)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Index.cshtml(TempData.Peek can keep the tempdate value):

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="CategoryId" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="CategoryId" asp-items='@(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SelectListItem>>(TempData.Peek("Categories").ToString()))' class="form-control"></select>
        <span asp-validation-for="CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
   
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Category:

```
public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    }
```

result:
[image]